# How to summarize/compress data and show multiple answers in 1 cell

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm neck deep in this macro that I've created. My peers are requesting more on outputs than I had originally displayed. I need a macro that can do the following. So the question I have could normally be solved with VLOOKUP. However, in this case it is very important to know if there are really two answers and what both would be, making VLOOKUP obsolete. So lets say I have 2 columns. One showing Run # and the other showing Vertical, Curve, or Lateral (they progress down the column in that order). lets say Run #1 is Vertical. Run #2 began vertical, but finished curved. Run #3 is curve, but finished lateral. Finally, run #4 is lateral.Example:

```
Run#    Section
1       Vertical
1       Vertical
1       Vertical
2       Vertical
2       Vertical
2       Curve
2       Curve
3       Curve
3       Curve
3       Lateral
3       Lateral
4       Lateral
4       Lateral
4       Lateral
4       Lateral
```

What I need is this below. Basically before I would preform this, I would be using a pivot table with Run# in "Rows" and then collecting other data in it as well. I then will copy and paste the value's only to a different sheet where then I will need to add in the values in "section" as shown below.

```
Run#    Section
1       Vertical
2       Vertical & Curve
3       Curve & Lateral
4       Lateral
```

Thanks for taking a look at this guys. I've tried finding something on this, but nothing shows multiple results in the same cell. Any help is greatly appreciated! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I have a udf called `JOINDISTINCT` (code below) - you can use this in conjunction with an array formula to do what you need.

For the formula, assuming that your run data is in columns A and B and that column E has the distinct run list, in F2 have the array formula (entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
=JOINDISTINCT(IF($A$1:$A$16=E2,$B$1:$B$16,"")," & ")
```

Note that we don't use the whole column, just the populated range, in order to speed up execution. The array part checks column A values to be matching the run number in E2 and then will return the Section or blank. The JOINDISINCT takes that array and returns the distinct list, separated by (in this case) " & "

VBA Code for the function

```
Public Function JOINDISTINCT(rng As Variant, Optional separator = ", ") As String
  JOINDISTINCT = ""
  Dim v As String
  'Dictionary needs REFERENCE: Microsoft Scripting Runtime
  Dim dict As New Dictionary
  For Each c In rng
    If IsObject(c) Then
      v = c.Text
    Else
      v = c
    End If
    If v <> "" Then
      If Not (dict.Exists(v)) Then
        dict.Add v, 1
        If JOINDISTINCT = "" Then
          JOINDISTINCT = v
        Else
          JOINDISTINCT = JOINDISTINCT & separator & v
        End If
      End If
    End If
  Next c
  Set dict = Nothing
End Function
```